# Loop through 2 files perl

Tags: perl

I have an issue in Perl. 2 files.

FileA

```
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,2
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,09,3
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,10,3
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,13,2
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,09,3
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,10,3
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,13,2
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,09,3
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,10,3
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,13,2
```

FileB

```
DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 
DistA,1010101,a_0300,21
DistA,1010101,b_0200,21 
DistA,1010101,b_0300,19
```

and the resulting I have is this.

FileC

```
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,1
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,11,5
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,12,5
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,09,2
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,10,2
DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,13,1
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,11,5
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,12,5
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,09,2
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,10,2
DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,13,1
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,11,5
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,12,5
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,09,2
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,10,2
DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,13,1
```

But I want this result for each exactly at this sequence and subtracting 1 from 6th column of the FileB and if the value is equal to 0 I do not need to print. This is only an example because I need the similar result for each line of the FileA

I want to decrement FileA until 0 based on the match for the following fields.

```
DistA,1010101,a_0200.
```

So the decrement is that way.

FileNewC

```
Loop-1
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,2
Loop-2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,1
Loop-3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,5
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,5
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,1
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,1
Loop-4
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,4
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,4
Loop-5
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,3
Loop-6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,2
Loop-7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,1
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,1
```

My perl is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$|=1;

my $filea = $ARGV[0];
my $fileb = $ARGV[1];


open ( FA, '<', $filea) || die ( "File $filea Not Found!" );
open ( FB, '<', $fileb) || die ( "File $fileb Not Found!" );
#open ( FC, ">", $filec) || die ( "File $filec Not Found!" );

my %hash;
while ( <FB> ) {
    chomp;
    my($dist, $sec, $cls, $max) = split ",";
    push @{ $hash{$dist, $sec, $cls} }, $max;
}

while ( <FA> ) {
    chomp;
    my($dist, $sec, $cls, $add, $idx, $qtd) = split ",";

    for my $max ( @{ $hash{$dist, $sec, $cls } }){
        my $tot = $qtd -1;
        print join(",", $dist, $sec, $cls, $add, $idx, $tot)."\n";
         $qtd=$tot;

    }
}
```

Comment: The Second while is

     for my $max ( @{ $hash{$dist, $sec, $cls} }){
                                        my $tot = $qtd -1;
                                                print join(",", $dist, $sec, $cls, $add, $idx, $tot, $max  )."\n";
                                                $qtd=$tot;
    
                }

Comment: In *FileNewC* there is no max. How do you use max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use arrays in the case...so the code would look as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$|=1;

my $filea = $ARGV[0];
my $fileb = $ARGV[1];
my $action = $ARGV[2] || "n" ; 

open ( FA, '<', $filea) || die ( "File $filea Not Found!" );
open ( FB, '<', $fileb) || die ( "File $fileb Not Found!" );
#open ( FC, ">", $filec) || die ( "File $filec Not Found!" );

my @B;
while ( <FB> ) {
    chomp;
    my($dist, $sec, $cls, $max) = split ",";
    push @B, [$dist, $sec, $cls, $max];
}

my @A;
while ( <FA> ) {
    chomp;
    my($dist, $sec, $cls, $add, $idx, $qtd) = split ",";
    push @A, [$dist, $sec, $cls, $add, $idx, $qtd];
}

$i = 1;
my $j = 0;
my $k = 0;
while ( 1 ) {
    # -- keep looping til nothing is modified --
    my $modified=0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach my $row ( @A ) {
        # -- loop through FileA, $j is rowcount --
        $j++;
        $k=0;
        foreach my $line ( @B ) {
            # -- loop through FileB, $k is linecount --
            $k++;
            my $idx1= @$line[0].@$line[1].@$line[2];
            my $idx2= @$row[0].@$row[1].@$row[2];
            if ($idx1 eq $idx2) {
                # -- has to match on the index fields --
                my $max = @$line[3];
                my $tot = @$row[5] -1;
                if ( $tot > 0 ) {
                    # -- only print if modified and result is >0 --
                    # -- only print loop header if 1rst time through inside loop --
                    if (! $modified) { print "Loop-".$i++."\n"; }
                    if ($action eq "d") {
                        print "FileB[".$k."]: ".join(",", @$line[0],@$line[1],@$line[2],@$line[3] )."\n";
                        print "FileA[".$j."]: ".join(",", @$row[0],@$row[1],@$row[2],@$row[3],@$row[4],@$row[5]  )."\n";
                    }
                    print "*FileA[".$j."]: ".join(",", @$row[0],@$row[1],@$row[2],@$row[3],@$row[4],$tot )."\n";
                    @$row[5]=$tot;
                    $modified = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ((! $modified ) || ($i > 50)) {
        # -- only exit if pass through entire loop with no modifications --
        # -- or we have looped too many times ... sanity check --
        last;
    }
}
```

to see extra detail call with 3rd argument set to 'd'

```
<filename> FileA FileB d
```

final output has been configured to prefix the file and Line# to clarify what is being modified.

Example of detail for loop-1 is
(note the modified lines begin with a *)

If this is NOT in the order you expect then we have to pre-sort the 2d-array created from FileA.  If that is the case you have to specify the sort order required.

```
Loop-1
FileB[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 
FileA[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,7
*FileA[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
FileB[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 
FileA[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,7
*FileA[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
FileB[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 
FileA[3]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,3
*FileA[3]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,2
FileB[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 
FileA[4]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,3
*FileA[4]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,2
FileB[1]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 
FileA[5]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,2
*FileA[5]: DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,1
FileB[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,21
FileA[6]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,11,6
*FileA[6]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,11,5
FileB[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,21
FileA[7]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,12,6
*FileA[7]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,12,5
FileB[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,21
FileA[8]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,09,3
*FileA[8]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,09,2
FileB[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,21
FileA[9]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,10,3
*FileA[9]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,10,2
FileB[2]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,21
FileA[10]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,13,2
*FileA[10]: DistA,1010101,a_0300,Address,13,1
FileB[3]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,21 
FileA[11]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,11,6
*FileA[11]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,11,5
FileB[3]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,21 
FileA[12]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,12,6
*FileA[12]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,12,5
FileB[3]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,21 
FileA[13]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,09,3
*FileA[13]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,09,2
FileB[3]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,21 
FileA[14]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,10,3
*FileA[14]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,10,2
FileB[3]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,21 
FileA[15]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,13,2
*FileA[15]: DistA,1010101,b_0200,Address,13,1
FileB[4]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,19
FileA[16]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,11,6
*FileA[16]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,11,5
FileB[4]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,19
FileA[17]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,12,6
*FileA[17]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,12,5
FileB[4]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,19
FileA[18]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,09,3
*FileA[18]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,09,2
FileB[4]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,19
FileA[19]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,10,3
*FileA[19]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,10,2
FileB[4]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,19
FileA[20]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,13,2
*FileA[20]: DistA,1010101,b_0300,Address,13,1
Loop-2
```

Comment: I got you the idea is really good but still does not work.
The result I got only for line DistA,1010101,a_0200,23 from FileB is that:

    DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
    DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
    DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,2
    DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,2
    DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,1

I need to follow the sort from 6th column, in this case, the result (11=>6,12=>6,09=>2,10=>2,13=>1).

But I need to decrement -1 by every value starting from FileA until all positions become 0.

Comment: I put another for inside the foreach by $qtd 

foreach my $line ( @h ) {
        my $max = @$line[3];
        my $tot = $qtd -1;
        for (1..$qtd){
              if ( $tot > 0 ) {
            print join(",", $dist, $sec, $cls, $add, $idx, $tot, $max  )."\n";
            $qtd=$tot;
        }
}

Comment: and I got a result approximate but not for the sort I want.

Loop-1
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
Loop-2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
And so on.

Comment: But the correct is: 

Loop-1
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,7
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,3
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,2
Loop-2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,11,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,12,6
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,09,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,10,2
DistA,1010101,a_0200,Address,13,1
and so on.

Comment: I am sorry....It is not clear what sort you are using.  Are you trying to say you wish to sort FileA rows based on column 6 in descending order prior to processing and then only process the lines with the first  (maximum) value?

Comment: Hi ebk. I have redone the 'answer' portion from scratch and added some labelling in the output to try to make it clear as to which lines are being modified and why.  If the output you want is actually the unmodfied line prior to it's change let me know.